# Print line when the 1st field in the 2nd line matches the previous line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
f1 |  f2  | f3
---  ----  ---
T1 | 0.10 | tx1  
T1 | 0.32 | tx2  
T2 | 0.16 | tx1  
T2 | 0.56 | tx3
T2 | 0.90 | tx2
```

What I want is to compare f1 value to the previous one and if it matches, print the whole line. Also if the f1 value occur more than 2 times, only get the 2nd one, so no repetition is allowed. This is just an example and the file contains 3, 4 and 5 occurrences of f1 and I would like to get those also.

Any ideas on that is appreciated as I could not get one yet! 
I tried this code but didn't work:

```
awk '{ if ($1 != old)  print; old = $1; }' foo
```

My expected output looks like this:

```
f1 |  f2  | f3
---  ----  ---  
T1 | 0.32 | tx2   
T2 | 0.56 | tx3
```

Comment: please add all the cases in sample input(s) and provide expected output as well for clarity... and you need to show what you have tried as well

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I think the sample is enough to make my point but I will add what I tried.

Comment: thanks for adding what you've tried, I would suggest still to add expected output explicitly.. like do you need only lines matching criteria you've defined, do you want headers too, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ awk 'f1==$1&&hits[$1]==1{print}{f1=$1;hits[$1]++}' foo
T1 | 0.32 | tx2
T2 | 0.56 | tx3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @James Brown. That perfectly did it!

Comment: The array name `seen` is idiomatically used to depict a set, e.g. `!seen[$1]++`. Using that name in this context is misleading, you should be using an array named `count` or similar that better reflects what you are using the array for.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
f1 |  f2  | f3
---  ----  ---
T1 | 0.10 | tx1  
T1 | 0.32 | tx2  
T2 | 0.16 | tx1  
T2 | 0.56 | tx3
T2 | 0.90 | tx2  

$ awk 'seen[$1]++ == 1 || NR < 3' ip.txt 
f1 |  f2  | f3
---  ----  ---
T1 | 0.32 | tx2  
T2 | 0.56 | tx3
```